# Yii2: can I $this->render(..) and then execute sql command?

Tags: performance, yii2, pagespeed, yii2-advanced-app

I have an idea how speed up page load. I have sql command that I need to execute in controller. What if I try to execute after rendering page? Rendering vars (`model`) does not depend on it.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Model();

    ...

    $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

    Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE ...')->execute();

    return;
}
```

Comment: Execute it as Ajax once the page loads. Or cache the page/query

Answer (score 2):

You could use "afterRender" to do some stuff if your really want to execute something after render.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#afterRender%28%29-detail

```
$this->view->on('afterRender', ...);
```

or globally set in app/config/main.php

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'on afterRender' => function ($event) {
                /** @var $event yii\base\ViewEvent */

            },
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In yii2 the the result of the render is returned to to the caller function..

this way

```
return $this->render('index', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
```

otherwise is not showed ..
ther your code or not show the index page or not execute the sql command..

what do you are trying to do don't speed up the page load simple ( i think ) you try to do  another think when the page is loading..